# How to limit the number of posts on the home page?

Tags: query-posts

I am working on my first WP site and am having some difficulty. In my theme's index.php page, I see the following code:

```
<?php 
query_posts(array(
  'category__not_in' => array($headline),
  'post__not_in' => $postnotin,
  'paged' => $paged,
  'numberposts' => 5
));
if ( have_posts() ): $postCount = 0; ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $postCount++;?>
[more code....]
```

So - you see I'm trying to limit the number of posts on the home page to 5, which I thought was the default. Anyways, it is showing more than 5 and I can't seem to get it to work. I've tried "posts_per_page" without luck. If my theme is overwriting it, any ideas where that may be?

FWIW, I'm using the initiator theme by colorlabs

Thanks!!!

Comment: `numberposts` is the old parameter, you should be using `posts_per_page`. Right now, I believe they are identical in function, but `numberposts` is depreciated, so you cannot count on it to be available with the next release of wordpress.

Comment: Thanks, m0r7if3r. Updating it with posts_per_page doesn't work either. I have a feeling the theme is over writing it. I don't want to do some php counting hack but am about ready to...

Comment: Have you checked the appropriate filters and actions?

Comment: That's already beyond me. I'm gonna go google it now :)

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224209/wordpress-how-do-i-get-all-the-registered-functions-for-the-content-filter) will get you started. You may just want to `print_r( $wp_filter` )` and look at everything, but that's gonna generate a massive list that may or may not be of use to you.

Comment: I ended up just throwing a php counter in there. not worth hours when I can hack it in 30 seconds!!!

Comment: Add your solution as an answer, with working code, and mark the question as _answered_. Thanks!

Comment: If you have any sticky posts, those aren't counted by posts_per_page. Ex: you set the limit to 5 and you have 3 sticky posts. WP displays 8 posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's what I ended up doing:

```
<?php 
query_posts(array(
'category__not_in' => array($headline),
'post__not_in' => $postnotin,
'paged' => $paged,
'posts_per_page' => 5
));
if ( have_posts() ): $postCount = 0; ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $postCount++;
if ($postCount < 6) {
?>
[all my code]

<?php } #end if ?> 
<?php endwhile;?>
```